# Is there a way to write this without doing useRef(socketRef)

Tags: reactjs

The code below is a simple implementation of xterm-for-react but eslint keeps insisting that I need to useRef for the socket created in the useEffect. OK I've done that - but it's left me wondering if there is a way to get around that. useRef is usually supposed to be for getting a ref to a DOM element (or psuedo-DOM element) so is this actually a valid way to use it here - or is there a way to do this without useRef - or an even better way?

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { XTerm } from "xterm-for-react";
import io from "socket.io-client";
import "./TerminalForm.css";
const connectAddress = "http://localhost:8080";

function TerminalForm() {
  const xtermRef = useRef(null);
  const socketRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    connectToSocket()
      .then((socket) => {
        socketRef.current = socket;
        xtermRef.current.terminal.write(`\r\n$ `);        
        socketRef.current.on("output", (data) => {
          xtermRef.current.terminal.write(data);
        });
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.log("Error Failed to connect to server: ", e);
      });
    return function cleanup() {
      socketRef.current.disconnect();
    };
  }, []);

  const onDataCallback = (data) => {
    if (socketRef.current) {
      socketRef.current.emit("input", data);
    }
  };

  const connectToSocket = () => {
    return new Promise((res) => {
      const socket = io(connectAddress);
      res(socket);
    });
  };

  return (
    <div id="terminal-container">
      <XTerm
        className={"xterm"}
        ref={xtermRef}
        onData={onDataCallback}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default TerminalForm;
```

Comment: Refs are not just for connecting to the DOM. They store any value you want to persist between renders. Why would you not want to use a ref here?

Comment: Because my senior colleague questioned why I was doing it this way and it made me think I was missing something! Perhaps he was just messing with me :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with this code. Since you need the original socket for the lifetime of XTerm then you need to store it somewhere.

You could store the socket in a `useState` hook. This will re-render the component once you set the socket. This way you can show a loading screen during connection, by checking if the state is null. Then display XTerm once the socket is set. (Which might not be what you want.)

Get your colleague to explain what is wrong with it according to them.